# vim substitution - remove trailing whitespaces except for new lines

Tags: regex, xcode, vim

A lot of vim users like to automatically trim whitespaces when writing their buffers using the following command:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py :%s/\s\+$//e
```

The regex itself being: `\s\+$` to grab any whitespaces at the end of a line.

This works well except when there are newlines in a file created by Xcode or relative.

To illustrate the problem, this is the output of a `git diff` after applying the substitution to some file with a single newline for reference:

```
-
+
```

My question is:

- This seems to happen because of the way Xcode handle newlines (see EDIT below)
- How could I modify the original vim substitution regex to avoid this from happening? (I tried stuff like `:%s/\(^\n\)\s\+$/\1/e` with no success).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This seems to be a problem only in the case where the developer doesn't have the "including whitespace-only lines" option checked in Preferences in Xcode **(disabled by default)**.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why that regex would change anything on the last line at all. Does Xcode insert a newline with trailing spaces on it?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem that's my current guess.

Comment: Can you try with this command `:%s/\s*\(\n\|\%$\)/\1/e` ?

Comment: @Meninx That didn't change anything unfortunately :*(

Comment: Does this happen only at the end of the file? Could you try with `set noeol` on your .vimrc?

Comment: @iovis This happens all over the file, meaning for each newline there is, there will be a sub applied.

Comment: Is vim an acient regex? In multi-line 
mode if string contains more than 1 
line, or even non-multi-line mode, the 
\s will match all newlines up to the EOL
or EOS. Where both are terminated via $ 
by an non-newline. Thus 
LINE-1`\t\t\n`\nLINE-2`\t\t\n\n\n\t\t` are 
matched. If it supports classes, it's 
better to use `[^\S\r\n]+$` which will work 
in any mode and not remove newlines. And
will match only 
LINE-1`\t\t`\n\nLINE-2`\t\t`\n\n\n`\t\t`

Comment: I very much doubt Xcode adds either a "new line" or a "newline".

Comment: I've tested with XCode and I happen to have that autocmd in my vimrc. The only thing that changed was the EOL. Can you upload an example file or something?

Comment: I edited the main question, this seems to only happen when a specific option is not checked in Xcode's preferences (which is disabled by default).

Comment: So, enable that option and the problem is solved, right?